# Using maven dependency to fetch tomcat-websocket-api results in exception Upgrade Failed

Tags: maven, tomcat, websocket

I created a simple Websocket app and attempting to test it against tomcat version 7.0.53.  When I build my application, I fetch the tomcat-websocket-api jar file by using the following Maven dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-websocket-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.53</version>
</dependency>
```

This works, in that the app builds OK. When I deploy my war file to tomcat and try to connect to the websocket endpoint defined by my app, it fails, and the following exception is shown in the tomcat logs:

```
May 13, 2014 12:29:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/WebSocketRestApp] threw exception [Upgrade failed] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Upgrade failed
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(UpgradeUtil.java:190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found that if I remove the dependency on tomcat-websocket-api as shown above from the pom.xml file, and instead I manually copy the jar file tomcat-websocket-api-7.0.53.jar from the tomcat installation, and build my war against that jar file, then I can connect to the websocket without a problem.

The two jar files (one bundled with tomcat, the other downloaded by maven) are the same size, but something must be different about them. I would prefer to download the jar file from the maven repo, but I'm not sure why that isn't working. Any suggestions appreciated.